# php merge regex

Tags: php, regex

I have two regex. First one (`'/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\-p{Cyrillic}]/u'`) remove all non alphanumeric characters except hyphens and second (`'!\s+!'`) replace multiple spaces with a single space. Can I merge?

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\-p{Cyrillic}]/u', '', preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $str));
```

Comment: Run this code and tell us.

Comment: No, because you have two different replacements. You need to run two different `preg_replace`

Comment: _"Can I merge?"_ - what is the result of your tests?

Comment: Perhaps. `preg_replace('~[^A-Z0-9\s\p{Cyrillic}]+|(\s){2,}~ui', '$1', $text);` will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Can I merge?"*

Not really with your approach because you have two different replacement strings.

However if I assume that you don't want something like `ABC,DEF` to become `ABCDEF` but to stay two separated words `ABC DEF` (unlike what does your first replacement), you can write:

```
$str = preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z\p{Cyrillic}-]+~ui', ' ', $str);
```

*(Note that this time, the white-spaces are included in the character class.)*

This way any sequence of characters that aren't letters, digits or that are white-spaces, is replaced with a single space in one pass.

Eventually all you have to do after is to trim the result string.

---

Other approach: instead of replacing all that you don't want in the string, extract what you want and join:

```
if ( preg_match_all('~[0-9a-z\p{Cyrillic}-]+~ui', $str, $matches) )
    $result = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
```